# How does stooge sort works?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

Stooge sort is a sorting algorithm described below:

```
Stooge-Sort(A,i,j)
if(A[i]>A[j]])
  then exchange(A[i],A[j])
if i+1>=j 
  then return
k = [(j-i+1)/3]
Stooge-Sort(A,i,j-k)
Stooge-Sort(A,i+k,j)
Stooge-Sort(A,i,j-k)
```

The algorithm has a terrible running time and I know that.
**Question:** I want to know how does this algorithm work?

Comment: `if(A[i]>A[]])` must be `if(A[i]>A[j]])`

Comment: Just "play computer" with a short array, a pencil, and paper--easiest way to figure out code is to execute it in your head (or use a debugger and step, but I'm a fan of relying on manual labor sometimes :)

Answer (score 5):

You sort the first and last element of your subarray. (Swap if required)

Then you recursively sort the first 2/3<sup>rd</sup> of subarray, last 2/3<sup>rd</sup> of subarray and again first 2/3<sup>rd</sup> of subarray.

To prove the correctness you can use induction.

```
1. Clearly this algo works for 0, 1 and 2 element array.
2. Assuming it works for all arrays shorter than subarray
   [i, j] let's prove it works for array[i,j] also. Let's
   divide range[i,j] in 3 parts x, y and z;
    a. After Stooge-Sort(A,i,j-k), or [xy], every element in range
       y are larger than that of x. (Because range [xy] has
       lesser elements than range[i,j])
    b. After Stooge-Sort(A,i+k,j), or [yz], all largest elements
       have moved to z and are sorted. So z is sorted and contains
       largest elements of the array.
    c. After Stooge-Sort(A,i,j-k), or [xy], first (2/3)rd part of
       array is also sorted making the complete array sorted.
```

From steps a, b and c, we can conclude parts x, y and z are sorted and all element of x are larger(or equal) than y, and all elements of z are (larger or equal) than z and that the complete array is sorted.

Answer (score 2):

It uses a divide and conquer tactic.

```
Set i = list first element index , j = list last element index
Set list item at position i = min(list value at position i, list value at position j)
Set list item at position j = max(list value at position i, list value at position j)
If (j - i) <= 1 return sorted list 
Else Set t = (j - i + 1) / 3 
Call sort with {i = i, j = j - t} then {i = i + t, j = j } then {i = i, j = j - t}
```

Lets say I want to sort array `[1,4,5,3,-6,3,7,10,-2,-5]` this sort would start:

```
Before: [1,4,5,3,-6,3,7,10,-2,-5] (i=0 ;j=9)
Before: [-5,4,5,3,-6,3,7,10,-2,1] (i=0 ;j=6)
Before: [-5,4,5,3,-6,3,7,10,-2,1] (i=0 ;j=4)
Before: [-6,4,5,3,-5,3,7,10,-2,1] (i=0 ;j=3)
Before: [-6,4,5,3,-5,3,7,10,-2,1] (i=0 ;j=2)
Before: [-6,4,5,3,-5,3,7,10,-2,1] (i=0 ;j=1)
After: [-6,4,5,3,-5,3,7,10,-2,1] (i=0 ;j=1)
Before: [-6,4,5,3,-5,3,7,10,-2,1] (i=1 ;j=2)
After: [-6,4,5,3,-5,3,7,10,-2,1] (i=1 ;j=2)
Before: [-6,4,5,3,-5,3,7,10,-2,1] (i=0 ;j=1)
After: [-6,4,5,3,-5,3,7,10,-2,1] (i=0 ;j=1)
After: [-6,4,5,3,-5,3,7,10,-2,1] (i=0 ;j=2)
Before: [-6,4,5,3,-5,3,7,10,-2,1] (i=1 ;j=3)
Before: [-6,3,5,4,-5,3,7,10,-2,1] (i=1 ;j=2)
After: [-6,3,5,4,-5,3,7,10,-2,1] (i=1 ;j=2)
Before: [-6,3,5,4,-5,3,7,10,-2,1] (i=2 ;j=3)
After: [-6,3,4,5,-5,3,7,10,-2,1] (i=2 ;j=3)
Before: [-6,3,4,5,-5,3,7,10,-2,1] (i=1 ;j=2)
After: [-6,3,4,5,-5,3,7,10,-2,1] (i=1 ;j=2)
After: [-6,3,4,5,-5,3,7,10,-2,1] (i=1 ;j=3)
Before: [-6,3,4,5,-5,3,7,10,-2,1] (i=0 ;j=2)
Before: [-6,3,4,5,-5,3,7,10,-2,1] (i=0 ;j=1)
After: [-6,3,4,5,-5,3,7,10,-2,1] (i=0 ;j=1)
Before: [-6,3,4,5,-5,3,7,10,-2,1] (i=1 ;j=2)
After: [-6,3,4,5,-5,3,7,10,-2,1] (i=1 ;j=2)
Before: [-6,3,4,5,-5,3,7,10,-2,1] (i=0 ;j=1)
After: [-6,3,4,5,-5,3,7,10,-2,1] (i=0 ;j=1)
After: [-6,3,4,5,-5,3,7,10,-2,1] (i=0 ;j=2)
After: [-6,3,4,5,-5,3,7,10,-2,1] (i=0 ;j=3)
Before: [-6,3,4,5,-5,3,7,10,-2,1] (i=1 ;j=4)
Before: [-6,-5,4,5,3,3,7,10,-2,1] (i=1 ;j=3)
Before: [-6,-5,4,5,3,3,7,10,-2,1] (i=1 ;j=2)
After: [-6,-5,4,5,3,3,7,10,-2,1] (i=1 ;j=2)
Before: [-6,-5,4,5,3,3,7,10,-2,1] (i=2 ;j=3)
//etc
```